# Идентификация посетителей

Tags: php, веб-программирование, безопасность

Имеется закрытый раздел на сайте. Задача поставлена таким образом, чтобы при переходе по прямой ссылке в закрытый раздел осуществлялась идентификация, в случае успеха - открывается закрытый раздел, в случае неудачи - производится перенаправление на публичный раздел сайта (если точнее, на страницу ошибки 404) Вопрос: каким образом, по какому набору атрибутов можно организовать идентификацию? В данный момент реализовано следующее решение - по белому списку IP адресов, но недостаток его в том, что у некоторых людей из белого списка меняется IP адрес, поэтому это неудобно. Какие еще существуют способы реализовать такую логику?

Answer (score 1):

Логин/пароль, сертификат в браузере...

Comment: Вот закрытие сайта сертификатом https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-cerfiticate_management_02/

Comment: Логин/пароль уже есть. Сертификат - вы имеете ввиду ssl? Он тоже есть. НО! Для случайного посетителя все должно выглядеть так, будто данного раздела вовсе не существует, поэтому я и пишу, что в случае неудачи идет перенаправление на 404. Т.е. нужен такой способ, который кроме логина/пароля смог идентифицировать посетителя.

Comment: Хотите странного. Сначала надо идентифицировать пользователя, а потом ему показывать разделы, если хотите скрыть. Иначе любой запрос будет раскрывать существование такого раздела. 
Т.е. создаем форму авторизации (можно необязательную). На определенные разделы вешаем авторизацию с обработкой. Только вместо стандартных редиректов 301 на форму авторизации делаете header с 404
Фреймворков и библиотек с готовой авторизацией полно. Найти, прикрутить, допилить

Comment: Ну как странно? Злоумышленник, узнав, где у сайта закрытый раздел будет направлять атаки туда, правильно? Если он не узнает, где есть такой раздел, он не знает куда направить атаки, логично? Другими словами, первый рубеж защиты - это то, что доступ к авторизации в закрытом разделе тоже не для всех. Ну или понимайте это как дополнительную меру безопасности, такая вот паранойя.

Comment: Идентификация != авторизация, т.е. под идентификацией я понимаю способ определения посетителя в один из двух классов: доверенные, либо не доверенные. А авторизация - это частный случай идентификации, когда требуется показывать форму ввода логина/пароля, что дает понять, что этот раздел закрытый и доступ к нему ограничен.

Comment: А может есть способ добавить какой-нибудь признак в заголовки запроса посетителя?